# Is this video about an Uighur family being forced to live with Han Chinese men genuine?

Tags: china, video, genocide

The following video was posted to a number of social media platforms:

["Uyghur women being forced to serve Han Chinese"](https://www.reddit.com/r/JoeRogan/comments/ohob7b/uyghur_women_being_forced_to_serve_han_chinese/)

[image: man grabs woman]
[image: girl wash leg]
[image: smoking and massage]

In the video, an Asian male is recording himself sitting on the couch. He grabs the hand of an Asian woman, who escapes from the grab with a seemingly tired anger. In the next scene, a roughly 10 years old girl brings water, and washes the legs of the man, and then a teenager-looking girl does the same. In the last scene, we see two male in the same place, one is smoking while the younger girl is hugging him, and the other is recieving massagge from another young woman. The men have a grin smile during the whole video. The caption of the video says:

> These Han Chinese are living in the home of an Uyghur female and her daughter as government-assigned "relatives". Her husband might be in a prison or concentration camp.

There are a number of reports about the issue commonly referred by reputed media as Uighur genocide (e. g. [1](https://edition.cnn.com/2021/03/09/asia/china-uyghurs-xinjiang-genocide-report-intl-hnk/index.html),[2](https://www.bbc.com/news/world-asia-china-55794071),[3](https://www.bbc.com/news/world-asia-china-22278037)), and many of them report such instances of "forced relatives". My question is, do we know if this specific video is genuine?
Specifically, do we know

- whether the people recorded are indeed Han Chinese and Uighurs,
- whether the video is a genuine reflection of their daily life, or staged by someone(s), and
- whether these men are indeed assigned by government to live together with the family? (As opposed to, for example, being genuine relatives, or using means of thread and/or criminal activity.)

I understand it may be impossible to answer these questions, but it's a common accusation by Chinese media that these videos are fake; therefore, it would be nice to reveal some background.

Comment: Can you add a link to a Chinese media report that this video is fake?

Comment: Unfortunately not at the moment, but I will look into it. In any case, CCP actively denies any of it's alleged wrongdoings against the Uighurs, so it'm very positive I can practically be taken as granted that they deny any of the statements mentioned in the video. Someone with a knowledge of Mandarin would be able to help me out with finding sources in Chinese language.

Comment: I have no evidence the would justify an answer, [this has been reported](https://www.aljazeera.com/news/2018/11/30/uninvited-guests-keep-watch-for-china-inside-uighur-homes) [on previously](https://www.hrw.org/report/2018/09/09/eradicating-ideological-viruses/chinas-campaign-repression-against-xinjiangs)

Comment: @Dave: also by CNN: https://edition.cnn.com/2018/11/09/opinions/uyghur-home-visit-opinion-intl/index.html